Synonymizing the "word-meaning" tag to the "meaning" tag
As it stands the word-meaning and meaning tags are two separate tags.
They share an almost identical excerpt:
word-meaning's excerpt:

Questions related to the definition and nuance of meaning of a word or phrase

meaning's excerpt:

This tag is for questions related to definitions and nuances of meaning of a word or phrase.

Is there any reason to not synonymize the narrower word-meaning to the broader meaning, much as it has been done already on English Language & Usage?
I agree that technically word-meaning is a subset of meaning, and that reasonably by synoymizing word-meaning to meaning browsing questions / answers tagged word-meaning would end up showing also questions / answers tagged meaning, but as it stands browsing questions tagged meaning won't show questions tagged word-meaning, which should instead. Another point is: is it really important to distinguish between the meaning of a word or a, say, phrase when looking up questions / answers? Shouldn't the purpose of the word-meaning tag be to group questions about the meaning of a word under meaning in general? Wouldn't it be more convenient expecially when browsing questions?
Also, quoting the related FAQ on Meta.SE:

In some cases, tags that are subsets of other tags will also be considered synonyms, such as java-se for java.


Many thanks for your suggestions, @kos.
Initially, we wanted to keep word-meaning for the meaning of single words, while leaving meaning for expressions or a combination of words (even if they don't form a proper phrase). The reason for such a distinction is that sometimes users don't ask for the meaning of the whole phrase - they want to know just the meaning of a word in a certain context. Note that EL&U has separate tags for "meaning in context" and "single word requests," which we don't have on Italian.SE.
Still, I think you are right in underlining that browsing questions tagged meaning should also show questions tagged word-meaning. If other users will agree with you, please, feel free to add a tag synonym.

Thanks for your answer, If there's going to be agreement on this I'll surely will as long as I have enough reputation to do so, or I'll kindly ask someone else to do that for me. I think a score of 10 would be an appropriate threshold; if someone disagrees on this please let me know.

I agree with @kos. In addition, that would be consistent with the fact that the tag "usage" has been defined as a synonym of the tag "word-usage". But I would like to know the opinion of other users.

As @kos has suggested, I think a good way to express that we agree with this idea would be to vote this answer.
